# User's password update via WP REST API

Tags: ios, wordpress, api, rest, jwt

I'm developing an iOS app that connects a WP REST API with JWT. The API and the JWT plugin (JWT Authentication for WP-API) are working ok.

The app login is based in wordpress user and password and you can change your user password from it. After updating the user's password (`/wp-json/wp/v2/users/id?password=newpass`) the API stops working. I can't keep on doing any update call (updates, deletes, change the password again...) and the response is always:

```
{
  "code": "rest_cannot_edit",
  "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit users.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

This happens not only in the app but using postman too. 
In summary, I can only change once a user password via WP REST API and using JWT plugin.

If I change the password in the app and then I change it via Postman, the password can be updated from the app, but again, only once. (even with the same token)

Generate a new token doesn't work, restarting the app allows (with a new token) change the pass again.

Comment: have you tried any thing in code?

Comment: I don't understand you, sorry. I have an app in swift doing all the job. The app get info through the WP REST API and it's working ok. The problem is when I change the password via the API, after that moment all the API calls stop working.

Comment: Have you check the code when you update password

Comment: Yes, the code seems to be ok, actually It works properly but only once. I don't know what it's going on. It's seem to be something related with wordpress user permission after updating the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've experienced the same problem as you. After changing the user's password, your HTTP client keeps the **old** auth cookie with it. That means `wordpress_logged_in` cookie still references user's old password, getting an 401 error. 
After changing user's password via API, just clear your client's cookies. Test it first on Postman following these steps:

1. Make an API request changing user's password normally.
2. Make another API request changing user's password or its details. Note that 401 error will appear.
3. In your Request screen, click on *Manage Cookies*.
4. In the cookies list, select your wordpress site, and delete the `wordpress_logged_in` cookie.
5. Repeat the API request on item 2.